Unable to import mbtiles generated with MapTiler in Mapbox studio
I’m trying to import a tileset generated from a QGIS vector shapefile processed by MapTiler in Mapbox. I tried generating compressed and uncompressed mbtiles with a size of 512px, the resulting files throws an « unknown format ». I also tried generating a geopackage : no luck there as Mapbox studio doesn’t list .gpkg as supported.
In fact, I tried MapTiler engine every export option. None allowed to import the data in Mapbox studio.
My question is how do I get data generated with MapTiler in Mapbox Studio ?
I’m stucked, thx for any pointers you might suggest.

I have tried a few different MBTiles made with MapTiler Engine, and they work fine on all platforms: Studio, QGIS, etc. If possible, I'd send your original file to support@maptiler.com. They could test converting your data and see where the issue lies. I'm certainly not getting any problems with the datasets I used.
